# Flag Counts for Questions, Answers & Comments?

Tags: discussion, flags

Why are there only 2 lists, one for comments and one for questions and answers?

I think answers should get their own flag count.
Did you already had discussions about that?

Are their any points against it?

When I flag a question (normally Off-Topic) it's something completely different to me than flagging an answer (normally not an answer).

Comment: Curently I have 13 Flags in Total - its 9am UTC and there are just 2 left. 2/11 Flags I used, I used for Answers. 4 of them are still active the rest was marked helpful. just this 10 Flags in the beginning are really strict!

Answer (score 1):

The amount of flags you can cast each day is separated by posts and comments. For example, I get 100 flags that I can use each day for comments and another 100 flags I can use each day for posts *(questions and answers)*.

So that's likely one reason why the question and answer flags are grouped together. If they allowed say 100 flags for questions, 100 for answers, and 100 for comments, I could see them being separated.

Once you get 3k reputation, you will start using close votes instead of flags for questions that need to be closed. Thus, it would be practically implausible to flag 100 questions a day that would be considered "helpful". For example, I only run into maybe 5 questions a day that need to be flagged, and use my 50 close votes to vote to close.

Comment: Yeah I know about that 2 Different Counts, but for me it would make much more sens to group comments and answers

Comment: why? comments that need to be flagged get left on questions too

Comment: Yes thats true, but even when its under a Question it asks for further Information or gives some more Information wich probaply attempts to help getting an Answer

Comment: It might be true what you added in your edit, but I'm only having ~13 Flags a day and thats not much if you are active. Also ist a loong way to 3k Rep.